# How to update the first line of text in a text file in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, filestream

So the first line of my text file I want a header that contains a row count of all records that will be in the file.  So if there ends up being a 1000 rows in this file I want the first line to say 1000.  How can I do this?  I can get the row count to display at the end of the file but I want it on top.

Comment: Post your code how you get it to display at the end of file

Answer (score 3):

In C#.Net:

```
var filepath = "/file/path";
var list = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();
list.Insert(0, String.Format("Records in this file: {0}", list.Count));
File.WriteAllLines(filepath, list);
```

In VB.Net (I think, i dont really use VB)

```
Dim filepath = "/file/path"
Dim list = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList()
list.Insert(0, [String].Format("Records in this file: {0}", list.Count))
File.WriteAllLines(filepath, list)
```

Comment: You won't need the square brackets around String in VB.

Comment: @TonyLarson Not sure what is different in your test case, but this code does work in my tests.

Comment: @TonyLarson: Yes, the code does work. There is nothing to go wrong here. "Doesnt work" wont help us fix your problem. You should update your question with your attempt to use the code here and tell us what the problem is.